# CSS skipping the first <div>

Tags: html, css

So I'm working with a tool that allows me to provide CSS style sheets, but I'm facing some issues.

In my original HTML code I have many DIV's inside DIV's, which makes it a little hard to fix the code. In my original code the DIV's stand for Groups, and at the first group I want to assign different styles as I do to the others.

In my example below, I'd like to add styles to the first `<div class="Test2">`, but not to the second and third. I've tried using :not(:first-child), or things like that as you can see, but none of them worked.

Please help me out!

```css
.Test1 {
  background: #ff0000;
  color: green;
}

.Test2 {
  color: blue;
}

.Test2 div:nth-child(1n+2) {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="Test1">
    <div class="Test2">
       <span>The first paragraph.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="Test3">
      <div>dummy</div>
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Test2">
       <span>The first paragraph.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="Test3">
      <div>dummy</div>
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Test2">
       <span>The first paragraph.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="Test3">
      <div>dummy</div>
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `.Test1 .Test2:nth-child(2) { border: 2px dashed #f00 }`

Comment: Please keep in mind, if one of the answers works for you, please mark them as the answer to help other peoples in the community to find their solution easier if they facing the same issue. You can do this by using grey marks (tick) beside answers (you can only choose one), for more information please read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Otherwise please tell us why all of the provided answers do not work for you.

Comment: Did you come up with a conclusion?

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to do this, you can use [`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type#:%7E:text=The%20%3Afirst%2Dof%2Dtype,a%20group%20of%20sibling%20elements.&text=Note%3A%20As%20originally%20defined%2C%20the,this%20is%20no%20longer%20required.) to make sure the first element with class `Test-2` and type `div` will be affected.

```css
.Test1 {
  background: #ff0000;
  color: green;
}

.Test2:first-of-type {
  color: blue;
}

.Test2 {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="Test1">
    <div class="Test2">
       <span>The first paragraph.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="Test3">
      <div>dummy</div>
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Test2">
       <span>The first paragraph.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="Test3">
      <div>dummy</div>
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Test2">
       <span>The first paragraph.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="Test3">
      <div>dummy</div>
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Other than these colours hurting my eyes; ``:first-of-type`` definitely sounds like what OP is after.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.Test2 div:nth-child(1n+2) {
  color: yellow;
}
```

Will make Test2's 1n+2'th child appear yellow. Test2 has only one child: `<span>The first paragraph.</span>`. You'll have to put the selector on the div above. (Test2 is the first child of Test1)

Answer (score -1):

All of them have the same class just change the class on other two or keep **Test2** as it is for common properties that you want to apply and if you want the first one to have different style you can give it a new class with any name and use that class to aplly proprites different from the rest of divs

Answer (score -1):

If i get it right, You want to achieve blue color just on The first paragraph.

```
.Test2:first-child{
Color:blue;
}
```

Should do that.